# How to Select TFS History based on System.ID

Tags: powershell, tfs

The script below allows me to get changeset history from `TFS`.  How can I get the history based on a `PBI number` or `System.ID`?

```
Get-TfsItemHistory $locationToSearch -Recurse -Version $dateRange | 
Sort CreationDate | Select ChangeSetId,Committer,Comment,CreationDate |  Format-Table ChangeSetId,CreationDate,Committer,Comment -Auto -Wrap  | 
out-file "C:\full.txt"
```

Comment: The changesets should be linked to a task and associated to a PBI (System.ID)

Comment: Did you mean you want to search out  all those changesets which associated a special PBI work item (known System.ID ) in your changeset history list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-TfsItemHistory` is a [commandlet  in tfspowertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703743/get-tfsitemhistory-version-parameter). It's not able to get what you want. You could use TFS Client API to achieve it, please refer the code sample from [*AlexanderM's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423721/finding-changesets-associated-with-the-work-item-or-having-specific-comment-tfs):

```
private static void GetChangesForWorkItem()
{
    var configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(new Uri(@"http://myserver:8080/tfs"));
    var tpcService = configurationServer.GetService<ITeamProjectCollectionService>();
    var collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
           new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
           false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

    var collectionNode = collectionNodes.First(x => x.Resource.DisplayName == "<collection name>");

    // Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
    Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
    TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);
    var vcs = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    var store = new WorkItemStore(collection);
    var workItems = new List<WorkItem>()
    {
        store.GetWorkItem(1123),
        store.GetWorkItem(1145),
    };

    var associatedChangesets = new List<Changeset>();

    foreach (var workItem in workItems)
    {
        foreach (var link in workItem.Links) 
        {
            if((link==null) || !(link is ExternalLink))
            continue;

            string externalLink = ((ExternalLink)link).LinkedArtifactUri;
            var artifact =LinkingUtilities.DecodeUri(externalLink);

            if (artifact.ArtifactType == "Changeset")
                associatedChangesets.Add(vcs.ArtifactProvider.GetChangeset(new Uri(externalLink)));
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(associatedChangesets.Select(x=>x.ChangesetId).OrderBy(x => x));
}
```

Another way is using [TFS RSET API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-links-and-attachments) and then filter out "relations" array with rel == "ArtifactLink"

```
   Get  https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=297,299,300&$expand=all&api-version=1.0
```